# Equivalent of Ruby's each_cons in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby, enumerator, equivalent

The question has been asked for many languages, yet not for javascript.

Ruby has the method [`Enumerable#each_cons`](https://devdocs.io/ruby~2.5/enumerable#method-i-each_cons) which look like that:

```ruby
puts (0..5).each_cons(2).to_a
# [[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
puts (0..5).each_cons(3).to_a
# [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

How could I have a similar method in javascript for `Array`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a function that will do it (ES6+):

```js
// functional approach
const eachCons = (array, num) => {
    return Array.from({ length: array.length - num + 1 },
                      (_, i) => array.slice(i, i + num))
}

// prototype overriding approach
Array.prototype.eachCons = function(num) {
  return Array.from({ length: this.length - num + 1 },
                    (_, i) => this.slice(i, i + num))
}


const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))

log(eachCons(array, 2))
log(eachCons(array, 3))

log(array.eachCons(2))
log(array.eachCons(3))
```

You have to guess the length of the resulting array (`n = length - num + 1`), and then you can take advantage of JavaScript's [`array.slice`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/slice) To get the chunks you need, iterating `n` times.

Comment: Alternate syntax for Array.from using internal mapper argument `Array.from({length:array.length - num + 1},
              (_, i) => array.slice(i, i + num))`

Comment: @UlysseBN, you can exclude your `map` completely and use the internal mapper itself, in case you didn't notice. There is definitely a performance increase in comparison to the solution you have right now mixed together.

Comment: @assoron - edited. I'm soo glad I posted this Q&A, it keeps getting better every minute.

Answer (score 3):

You could take the length, build a new array and map the sliced array with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and the build in mapper.

```js
Number.prototype[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this; i++) yield i;
};

Array.prototype.eachCons = function (n) {
    return Array.from({ length: this.length - n + 1}, (_, i) => this.slice(i, i + n));
}

console.log([...10].eachCons(2));
console.log([...10].eachCons(3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That [Symbol.iterator] over `Number` is definitely an interesting approach, I didn't know it would actually work.

Comment: (just a side note, it should be `<= this` in the Number iterator, since (0..5) actually is [0,1,2,3,4,5]).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a single line solution relying on function generators. Perhaps slightly different, but still worth to try out.

I've also added to the prototype, not sure why you would do that, but still..

This solution doesn't require ES6, it can be used with ES5 as well, with a bit of care for IE that doesn't support function generators at all.

```js
function* eachCons(arr, num) {
  for (let counter = 0; counter <= arr.length - num; counter++) yield arr.slice(counter, counter + num);
}

Array.prototype.eachCons = function* (num) {
  for (let counter = 0; counter <= this.length - num; counter++) yield this.slice(counter, counter + num);
}

const array = [0,1,2,3,4,5];
const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
log([...eachCons(array, 2)]);
log([...eachCons(array, 3)]);

// Iterable way
for (let [...pack] of eachCons(array, 2)) {
  console.log('pack is', pack);
}
// Prototype...
for (let [...pack] of array.eachCons(2)) {
  console.log('pack is', pack);
}
```

Comment: I like this a lot! However, I'd rather use a solution that gives back an array depending on the situation. For instance, the generator solution doesn't allow `eachCons([1,2,3,3], 3).map((a) => a[0] + a[1])`. +1 however, for the versatility and cleverness of that solution.

I wouldn't use the prototype solution, but I know some would so...

Comment: @UlysseBN Well, you could use: `Array.from` but you're right, that's a "downside" of generators :P

Comment: @UlysseBN perhaps it would make sense to don't return the generator on the prototype but, to rather return an array, though this would bring to confusion and inconsistency, but still, that would solve the issue (and would make sense if used against an array).

Comment: @UlysseBN as a side note, I've just noticed now that `to_a` is invoked in ruby, hence it's probably returning an iterator in ruby as well, but I'm not exactly sure.

Comment: @charlietfl you're right, indeed, that's a bit too much. Let me edit that :).

Comment: @briosheje it is returning an `Enumerator` in ruby. Which has access to the whole `Enumerable` interface. So not an `Iterator` js way, but not an `Array` either. I guess it really depends on the situation.

Comment: @UlysseBN I think a ruby `Enumerator` is actually quite similar to a javascript iterator, they should be quite similar as far as I can tell, and they should be similar to python's iterators and generators