# Javascript for loop and splice function

Tags: javascript

Good day, I have been trying to solve JS problem where I have an array a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]. I have to loop through an array and remove every three elements ie (1,1,1) do some logic, then the next three (1,1,2), and so on.

I have used for loop and splice

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]
tuple = ()

    for(j=0; j < a.length; j++){
        tuple = a.splice(j, 3)
    }
```

However, loop would not go beyond first round of (1,1,1).
What would be the correct way to loop through this array and remove sets of every three elements.
thank you.

Comment: Are you asking "How can I iterate over each set of 3 consecutive elements?"

Comment: where do you get `(1,1,2)` from?

Comment: Maybe something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477912/equivalent-of-rubys-each-cons-in-javascript)?

Comment: `.splice`ing an array while looping through it requires careful implementation (`.splice` mutates the array)

Comment: @tadman. yes I need to iterate over each set of 3 consec elements. out of array 'a' I have to remove 3 elements (1,1,1,) do some logic, and then take the next 3 (1,1,2) and repeat again.

Comment: Right, so did that answer help?

Comment: No, I probably don't understand what they are saying in the link you sent. If you could explain? thanks.

Comment: @NinaScholz (1,1,2) is an example of what I have to get out of array a. it's the first three elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`splice` changes the original array and that must be causing your issue.

So, you can use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) which returns a shallow copy of a portion of the original array (without modifying the original array):

```js
const a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4]

const doLogic = (arr) => {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)) // JSON.stringify is only for one-liner print. You can ignore it.
}

for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i++) {
  const picked = a.slice(i, i + 3)
  doLogic(picked)
}
```

Or this, if you want to pick the full array when length is less than 3:

```js
if (a.length < 3) {
  doLogic(a)
} else {
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length - 2; i++) {
    const picked = a.slice(i, i + 3)
    doLogic(picked)
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this is precisely what I needed. i will implement it now in my function.Great!

Answer (score 1):

**Splice** return removed elements from base array in given range. You probable want to use **slice** which only copy them and doesn't change primary array. You can also check this solution.

```js
let a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 4];

for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
    if ( j < a.length - 2 ) {
        const touple = [ a[j], a[j+1], a[j+2] ]
        console.log( touple )
    }
}
```